# What books to refer while preparing for rmo?

Tags: reference-request, contest-math

I am preparing for Regional Mathematics Olympiad and would like to know the books I should refer to prepare for the same. I basically would prefer the ones which enhance the ability to strike and which tells me about the  other methods by which I could have attempted the question.

Please suggest me books for RMO.

Comment: http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Mathematical-Olympiad-Handbook-Introduction/dp/0198501056

Comment: Euclid's *Elements* and all extant works of Archimedes.

Comment: Polya, *How to solve it?*

Comment: I would prefer books which emphasize on Rmo, the indian olympiad.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend 'Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics' by V Krishnamurthy, C R Pranesachar (New Age International Publishers). 
You may like to have a look at http://www.cmi.ac.in/~vipul/olymp_resources/

Answer (score 1):

Begin with Mathematical Circles or Challenge and thrill of Pre college mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "an excursion in mathematics"