# What books should I refer to while preparing for mathematical Olympiads, specifically IMO?

Tags: reference-request, contest-math, book-recommendation

I am from India and will be preparing for RMO (Regional Mathematics Olympiad) and INMO (Indian National Mathematics Olympiad). I need the best books for being able to qualify these and appear for IMO.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867257/, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192542/, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118585, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443117, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550307

Comment: I don't know which books, but if you just filter the questions with the tag (contest-math) in this website, you will find hundreds of problems of contest nature. There are currently [2831 questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contest-math?sort=newest&pageSize=50) with this tag,  with 353 of them unanswered. Maybe trying to answer these unanswered questions would be a good way to prepare ;)